# PDF for Normal-Gamma Mixture

Tags: function-construction

The normal-gamma mixture is:

```
NIntegrate[
 Evaluate[(Sqrt[a]*sd)^(-1)*
   PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], (x - mu)/(Sqrt[a]*sd)]*
   PDF[GammaDistribution[kr, kr^(-1)], a]], {a, 0, \[Infinity]}]
```

where the three variables are: mu - mean; sd - standard deviation; and kr - kurtosis. The mixture allows defining a "normal" distribution with kurtosis value greater than 3.

Instead of the clunky approach of defining the pdf as `func[mu_, sd_, kr_, x_]`, what is the correct syntax to use `ProbabilityDistribution`? The application in mind is to generate pdf tables for different kurtosis values.

Comment: Can't you use a straightforward `MixtureDistribution[]`?

Comment: The correct syntax of `ProbabilityDistribution` is described here:  http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProbabilityDistribution.html . I'm not sure what you are really asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That integral can be done analytically:

```
 dist[mu_,sd_,kr_] = ProbabilityDistribution[
            Assuming[ kr > 0 && sd > 0 && Element[{sd, x, mu, kr}, Reals],
            Integrate[(Sqrt[a]*sd)^(-1)*PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1],
                       (x - mu)/(Sqrt[a]*sd)]*
             PDF[GammaDistribution[kr, kr^(-1)], a], {a, 0, \[Infinity]}]],
                 {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

[image]

```
 Histogram[ RandomVariate[dist[1,.1,20], 1000] ]
```

[image]